# Typescript Fundamentals: Dynamic call of functions from an object that also contains strings

Tags: typescript

I have some problems getting the last line of this code to work:

```
const prompts = {
  bus_tickets: {
    en: 'Your bus tickets',
    de: 'Deine Bustickets',
  },
  signed_in_as: {
    en: (user: string) => `Signed in as: ${user}`,
    de: (user: string) => `Eingeloggt als: ${user}`,
  },
} as const

type TranslationKey = keyof typeof prompts

class I18n {
  userLocale: 'en' | 'de'

  constructor(userLocale: 'en' | 'de') {
    this.userLocale = userLocale
  }

  t(translationKey: TranslationKey) {
    const translations = prompts[translationKey]
    if (translations) return translations[this.userLocale]
    return ''
  }
}

// Function call
const i18n = new I18n("en")
i18n.t("signed_in_as")("Chris") // ERROR!
```

I understand the error message, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I hope you can help out here! The error message when I call `i18n.t("signed_in_as")("Chris")`:

```
This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type '"Your bus tickets" | "Deine Bustickets" | ((user: string) => string) | ""' are callable.
Type '"Your bus tickets"' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bus_tickets` the values of your object are strings, but in `signed_in_as` the values are functions.

You could either check the returntype before execution:

```js
const translation =  i18n.t('signed_in_as');
if(typeof translation === 'function') {
  console.log(translation('Chris'));
} else {
  console.log(translation);
}
```

Or you could normalize the types in your `prompts`-Object:

```js
const prompts = {
  bus_tickets: {
    en: () => 'Your bus ticket',
    // ...
  },
  signed_in_as: {
    en: (user: string) => `Signed in as: ${user}`,
    // ...
  }
};
```